# R package data.table fails to install/compile on system with R 3.5.1

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm trying to reinstall data.table with:

```
install.packages("data.table")
```

And I'm getting the following compile error:

```
forder.c: In function ‘range_str’:
forder.c:296: error: expected end of line before ‘update’
make: *** [forder.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
```

The package I'm getting from cran is: **data.table_1.12.0.tar.gz**
Which should be a version that works with 3.5, unlike the issues with data.table 1.10

The system this is on is RHEL 6.9 + I also already updated gcc via yum.

R versions are also up2date from yum: `R-core-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64` `R-core-devel-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64`

Everything I could find on google for this was either related to Rtools (Windows) or the older version 1.10, this seems like something else.

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: That is the full error message, above that are only a few compile steps that succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in the error message mentioned line is:

```
#pragma omp atomic update
```

which is functionality that is apparently not available in GCC before version 4.7 and on RedHat 6.9 the highest I get from standard repos is 4.4.7 at the moment.

Means I need a newer compiler, which can handle this openmp functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You can install an older version of data.table on EL6.  1.11.4 works; I'm not sure which, if any, newer versions do.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("data.table", version = "1.11.4")
```

More on installing older versions of packages: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Comment: version 1.11.8  works for me (but not 1.12.0) using gcc 4.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when installing data.table with R 3.5.0

On a CentOS 6.10 (which has gcc and g++ version 4.4.7), here is how I was able to install data.table:

1. `yum install devtoolset-6`
2. `scl enable devtoolset-6 bash`
   now if you do: `` `which gcc` -v `` , you should see a higher gcc version
3. `R`
   to start R 3.5.0
4. `install.packages("data.table")`
   now I was able to install data.table

Comment: I have the same versions of everything, but this did not work for me. My gcc version stays the same.